# Rails - Facebook Open Graph Story not shown in timeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, koala-gem

I have a problem with posting a custom OpenGraph story to the Facebook Timeline.

I am trying to post from an Rails Application via Koala-Gem:

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(self.facebook_user_access_token, FacebookService.facebook_keys[:app_secret])
@graph.put_connections('me', 'namespace:action', objcet: 'link/to/object')
```

My metadata from the object look like:

```
%meta{:property => 'og:type', :content => 'fitness.course' }
%meta{:property => 'fb:app_id', :content => 'an_app_id' }
%meta{:property => 'og:title', :content => 'Sample Post' }
%meta{:property => 'og:image', :content => 'link/to/sample_post.png' }
%meta{:property => 'og:url', :content => 'link/to/sample_post' }
%meta{:property => 'fb:explicitly_shared', :content => 'true' }
```

Even if I post the story through the Graph API Explorer the post only appears in the activity log but not in the Facebook Timeline.

I have set the `Explicitly Shared` option to `true` and have requested the `publish_actions` permission from the user.

Do i have to wait for the review of the app or is there a way to post it while developing?